# String to array or object

Tags: php, arrays, json, encode

Actually this is a string,

How can i convert it to object or array ..

```
{"kind": "delivery_quote", "fee": 750, "created": "2016-02-28T19:13:38Z", "expires": "2016-02-28T19:18:38Z", "currency": "usd", "duration": 60, "dropoff_eta": "2016-02-28T20:18:38Z", "id": "dqt_KhC5sbjq00Jn6F"}
```

I tried this

```
$array=explode(' ',$result);
$json = json_encode($result);
print($json);
```

It is giving me the result like this

```
"{\"kind\": \"delivery_quote\", \"fee\": 750, \"created\": \"2016-02-28T19:13:38Z\", \"expires\": \"2016-02-28T19:18:38Z\", \"currency\": \"usd\", \"duration\": 60, \"dropoff_eta\": \"2016-02-28T20:18:38Z\", \"id\": \"dqt_KhC5sbjq00Jn6F\"}"
```

But how can i do this properly so that i can take the results like

```
echo $json->fee;
```

Here is the [Eval](https://eval.in/527033) of what i have so far.

Help pls

Comment: try it with `json_decode`

Comment: have you tried `json_decode`?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$result = '{"kind": "delivery_quote", "fee": 750, "created": "2016-02-28T19:13:38Z", "expires": "2016-02-28T19:18:38Z", "currency": "usd", "duration": 60, "dropoff_eta": "2016-02-28T20:18:38Z", "id": "dqt_KhC5sbjq00Jn6F"}';

var_dump(json_decode($result));
var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to encode the json. [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) Returns the JSON representation of a value. If you want to convert json to array then you should use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) as :

```
$result = '{"kind": "delivery_quote", "fee": 750, "created": "2016-02-28T19:13:38Z", "expires": "2016-02-28T19:18:38Z", "currency": "usd", "duration": 60, "dropoff_eta": "2016-02-28T20:18:38Z", "id": "dqt_KhC5sbjq00Jn6F"}';
$json = json_decode($result);
echo $json->fee;
```

Which will give the value of fee as output :

```
750
```